# PHP - sessions log In problem

Tags: php

Okay when I log in as user 1 my PHP SESSIONS will stay logged in as user 1 until I leave or refresh the page and magically I'm logged in as user 2. What can be causing this problem?

Here is what I have at the top of all my pages.

```
 ob_start(); // Start output buffering.
 session_start(); // Initialize a session.
```

Here is some more code.

```
ob_start(); // Start output buffering.
session_start(); // Initialize a session.
$page = 'title';
include ('../includes/header.php');

require_once ('../includes/config.inc.php'); 
require_once ('../mysqli_connect.php'); // Connect to the db.

$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "aff", "adad", "adad");

if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {

    $url = BASE_URL . 'index.php'; // Define the URL.
    ob_end_clean(); // Delete the buffer.
    header("Location: $url");
    exit(); // Quit the script. 
}
```

Comment: unless we see some code absolutely anything could cause problems!!! and by code i don't mean the standard functions you call to do output buffering and session initialization.

Comment: Do you have some kind of cookie system in place?

Comment: Hello [again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588755/php-sessions-problem), @HELP.

Comment: @jnpcl or should I call you tron? WHO THE HELL IS HELP

Comment: no naughty words this time. show us your login function then we can HELP

Comment: But when I log in everything is fine until I refresh or leave the page.

Comment: $_SESSION['user_id'] is getting set or destroyed somewhere in your script. its impossible to answer unless we see the login function/query ect, output buffering has noting todo with your session.

Answer (score 0):

Are you destroying the sessions if you are logging in as user 2?

Comment: If i log in as user 2 everything seems to be okay?